# Redirecting a page when session expires using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dns

In my web.config file i have the following code:

```
<system.web>   
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>   
</system.web>
```

And I have main page Project and in that there will sub pages. I have given the `[Authorize]` attribute for each view index method.

After the session complete when we select any view then the page inside the project main page will be redirecting. But I want the whole page to be redirected.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web.config should look like the one below.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

the `<authentication>` element should be under `<system.web>` and not `<assemblies>`. The rest things you are doing it correctly i.e by putting `[Authorize]` attribute on method/action.

When the session expiries and a request is made for that action the loginUrl will be used and the user will be redirected to the login page. Hope this helps.

Comment: the `<authentication>` element should be under `<system.web>` and not `<assemblies>`.

Comment: Actually it is redirecting but my question is it is redirecting to every view page it should redirected to whole page. And it is only applicable to http request. But i want to do it for every child action in the page

Comment: what do you mean by "whole page" ?

Comment: suppose my page is Main. In that main page i have two partial pages separated by splitter. After session time out when i select any of the partial page in the partial page i am getting the login page. there fore there will be two partial pages when i click on two of the partial page. When i click on partial page also the Main page should be redirected